# GIT - Error: Project was not found as

Tags: git

I am having a problem with GIT and trying to push my local branch to the repo. When I try to push my branch I get the following error.

ERROR: Project was not found as "foobar"

Fatal: Could not read from repository.

I've tried to rename my local project to "foobar" but its not working. I still get the same error. 
What can be the cause of this error? Any input would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: To which repo?  Perhaps it doesn't exist remotely?

Comment: Its a repo in CodebaseHQ. The repo exists, and I can see the project.

Comment: what does `git remote -v` show

Comment: Shows the push and fetch statements for the repo.

Comment: It is probably an error message from CodebaseHQ, then. Does fetching work? Are you sure the output of `remote -v` is correct (i.e. the project name is right)?

Comment: The output of remote -v was not correct. Thanks guys for the input!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output of remote -v was not correct. In other words, the repo I was pushing to was not spelled correctly. I removed the original repo by git remote rm origin. Then I typed the correct repo and everything was ok.